# Button click force closes the app

Tags: android, sdk

I'm new in Android Development. I guess this is nooby question.
Q: I inserted 2 buttons to open 2 links and there were no code errors found in Android Studio but the app force closes on the action of click of the button. Any idea?

```
package com.domain.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class LinkButtons extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void goToBlue (View view) {
        goToUrl ( "http://www.google.com");
    }

    public void goToRed (View view) {
        goToUrl ( "http://www.facebook.com");
    }

    private void goToUrl (String url) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }

}
```

```
08-25 01:31:12.598  16635-16635/com.domain.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-25 01:31:12.600  16635-16635/com.domain.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.domain.app, PID: 16635
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method goToRed(View) in the activity class com.domain.app.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button_Red'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: goToRed [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4000)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

```
       <Button
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="RED"
            android:background="@drawable/button_red"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/button_Red"
            android:onClick="goToRed"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="15dp" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:text="BLUE"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/button_Blue"
            android:onClick="goToBlue"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Comment: From the LogCat, you are using this xml in `MainActivity.java` and your `goToRed()` method is in `LinkButtons.java`... this is why he can't find the method.

Comment: @Rami : You should have posted this as an answer.

Comment: @Squonk okey.. done!

Comment: `Could not find a method goToRed(View) in the activity class ml.shmshd.waupdater.MainActivity` what more can you possibly ask for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the LogCat, you are using this xml in `MainActivity.java` and your `goToRed()` method is in `LinkButtons.java`... this is why he can't find the method.

Comment: So, all the Java items should be in the MainActivity.java?

Comment: No!  But the method called in xml should be in the Activity that use that xml.

Comment: actually how is this (android:id="@+id/button_Red") identified in Java? What if I remove this ids from blue and red?

Comment: android:id="@+id/button_Red" is your Button id, if you remove it from xml you can't refer to this Button in java code.

Comment: So, if I change GoToGreen instead of GoToRed , I should change the idsto button_Green. Right?

Comment: No! the method called when your Button was clicked has nothing to do with your Button id ( unless you'll need to use the id in your method ).

Answer (score -1):

Even if you fixed it that way,.as mentioned above, on some devices or emulators it will not work, it's very better to use findViewById(R.id.....) .setOnClickListener(......

Comment: can I have an example?

Comment: are you saying that android documents behavior that are not supposed to reliable? do you have source for that?

Comment: I can remember it was nexus 4 on genymotion.... It was an activity that extends actionbarActivity.. forgot all other details